# Kotlin: ArrayList verification

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to developping in kotlin and for my class, I have a tic tac toe game to create. I initialy create a MutableListOf at the top of my page that contain all the "box" of my playing grid.

```
private var playingBoard:MutableList<ImageView> = ArrayList()
```

then i had all the boxes of the grid to the list using a function like so :

```
private fun activerGrilleDeJeu() {
    playingBoard.add(view.a1)
    playingBoard.add(view.a2)
    playingBoard.add(view.a3)
    playingBoard.add(view.b1)
    playingBoard.add(view.b2)
    playingBoard.add(view.b3)
    playingBoard.add(view.c1)
    playingBoard.add(view.c2)
    playingBoard.add(view.c3)
}
```

I then have a function that check for a victory when i click on an image view on the board but my problem is that function never seem's to trigger :

```
private fun victoryListener(): Boolean{
    //Horizontal victory
    if(playingBoard[0] == playingBoard[1] && playingBoard[0] == playingBoard[2] && playingBoard[1] == playingBoard[2]){
        return true
    }
```

this is how i call that function

```
grilleDeJeu[0].setOnClickListener {
        ajouterjeton(grilleDeJeu[0])
        if(victoryListener()){
            if(tourPresent == joueur1){
                joueur1.score += 1
                tourPresent = joueur1
                resultat("Victoire de ${joueur1.prenom}")
            }
            else{
                joueur2.score += 1
                tourPresent = joueur2
                resultat("Victoire de ${joueur2.prenom}")
            }
        }
```

I had the same function for every "box" of the grid so I didn't had all of them but if you guy's need the full code just ask and i'll post it.

Comment: You can't practically use `==` to compare two ImageViews. Even if they are displaying the same image, they are not considered equal because they are distinct UI elements. You should use a list of Ints, nullable Booleans, or some enum type to represent the state of each cell in the matrix. When a turn is played, update that list and then update the corresponding ImageView appearance to match the game board.

Comment: I'va just tried setTag() with the id of the drawable htat is displayed in the image view and it's working. i dont know if it's the best methods but it work for me so .. Thx a lot

Comment: That will work, but it's not good practice to store your game state inside the view elements. UI elements on Android should be thought of almost as ephemeral. Any configuration change will destroy and recreate all the views. Your game state should be stored in something in your ViewModel so it can survive configuration changes..